# Cannot set background-color in jQuery button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, togglebutton

I have a jQuery UI toggle button. When the button is clicked, I want to set the inside square to an arbitrary color. Here is jsFiddle that show the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/fvcdY/4/

When the button is clicked, I expect the black rectangle to become red, but, for some reasons, it stays black.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why manipulate inline styles and not classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var legend = $("<span/>", {
    text: ' ',
    style: 'display: inline-block; width: 13px; height: 13px;background-color:black',
    id: 'legend'
});
```

So now you can use this id instead of the variable:

```
input.button().click(function() {
    $('#legend').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JpECU/1/

Comment: Thanks. It worked. What still confuses me is that I can still handle input.click() event or make a input.button() or even check for input.is(':checked') on the input object but I cannot do input.css(). Do you know how is .css different from .is, .click or .button? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

lenged is an object that when is called will instantiate a new span element

You need use another var, after create the label, to store the reference to the appropiate span element.

after all, var legendInsideLabel = $("span").css(........)

This will work